# R exact match for multiple patterns

Tags: r, string

I would like to find exact matches for "A1" and "A6" in the vector:

```
myfile=paste("A",c(1:10),sep="")
```

I used `str_detect` from the `stringr` package:

```
toMatch <- c("A1", "A6")


str_detect(myfile,fixed(paste(toMatch,collapse="|")))
```

but it returns TRUE also for partial match with "A10".

Any other funs that could work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use the word boundary (`\\b`) to avoid the unnecessary partial matches

```
str_detect(myfile,paste0("\\b(", paste(toMatch, collapse="|"), ")\\b"))
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Based on the elements used, it can be done with `%in%`

```
myfile %in% toMatch
1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```